# Переобразование с BitConverter::ToInt16

Tags: c++-cli

Как переобразовать масив при помощи  BitConverter::ToInt16

```
String^ TimeCut() {
    SendIzohron(CutTime);

    byte arr [2];
    arr[0] = sim[0];
    arr[1] = sim[1];

    byte temp = arr[0];

    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = temp;


    int val = BitConverter::ToInt16(arr, 0);

    /*String^ s = (val * 4)->ToString() + " ms";
    textBoxInfoCutTime->Text = s;*/

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Что преобразовуется? Вы преобразуете в `val`, а на выход `sim`? У вас не получается ToInt16 или ToString которое закоментировано?

Comment: @nick_n_a не получается в ToInt16

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, может кому-то поможет) Всем спасибо)
     String^ TimeCut() {
        SendIzohron(CutTime);

```
    cli::array< Byte >^ arr = gcnew cli::array< Byte >(2);

    //Byte arr [2];
    arr[0] = sim[0];
    arr[1] = sim[1];

    byte temp = arr[0];

    arr[0] = arr[1];
    arr[1] = temp;


    int val = BitConverter::ToInt16(arr, 0);
    String^ s = Convert::ToString(val * 4) + " ms";


    return  s;
}
```